# How to automatically import signing a ClickOnce manifest on CruiseControl.NET

Tags: clickonce, cruisecontrol.net, nant

Currently when I try to sign a ClickOnce manifest, I manually click the "Select from File" button to load the .pfx file. I'm thinking about using [CruiseControl.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CruiseControl) to automatically import the .pfx file for those projects. Is there a way to implement this?

On the CruiseControl server, I use [NAnt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAnt). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your question strictly concerns CruiseControl.NET. Instead of selecting the PFX file through the GUI, find out how to do it through the command line. I think *[Signing and re-signing manifests in ClickOnce](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2009/04/29/signing-and-re-signing-manifests-in-clickonce.aspx)* might be helpful.

Then re-create the same process on CruiseControl.NET, using, for example, the [exec](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Executable_Task) task.

Answer (score 0):

I made a post a while ago how I did it with CCNet

it is more than just resign :-(
http://rubenwillems.blogspot.be/2009/02/continuous-installation-and-clickonce.html

other solutions are also possible, this is just one of them